# How can I change the Icon of the recycle bin on my mac?

Tags: macos, trash

So recently I saw a reddit post with changing the recylce bin icons to things eating your garbage files. This was very easy to implement on my PC, but at work I have grown tired of the standard mac trash bin as well.

The lovely redditor has his assets here https://github.com/sdushantha/recycle-bin-themes and I would love the work mac to have the hungry patrick star trash bin!

I'm not as comfortable on mac and all the tutorials I've found aren't working.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My MacOS is Monterey if this helps

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: The only info I've been able to find in google is from when the trash can mac pro was released in 2013. The steps are to navigate Machintosh HD > System > Library > CoreServices > Dock but I cant even figure that out. I'm a windows guy but at work we're an apple company... I'm kinda floundering a little

Comment: You can't change the content of `/System/...` any longer in Monterey.

Comment: So is it going to be possible to update my icons?

Comment: I don‘t know, there might be other ways.